# how to Write a if else condition in sqlserver 2008 insert data in a single table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi all i am workig in sql server 2008 and i don't have any idea to here i had written the 
script i am getting data from two columns  and i have two paths to call data
i want to chek that if in that two columns one column is empty or Blank i want to check 
in other path here  had written someting wrong could you plz help

Tahnks in Advance

```
DECLARE @xmltbl TABLE (ID INT, XmlData XML)
INSERT INTO @xmltbl(ID, XmlData) 
VALUES((select Id from News where sId=129),(select content from News where sId=129));
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http:microsoft.com')
SELECT ID, C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(1000)') DataText  FROM   @xmltbl
  CROSS APPLY
 XmlData.nodes('/BreezyCalc/Graph/point') n (C)

 select DataText from @xmltbl  

  if (DataText ="")
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @xmltbl(ID, XmlData) 
VALUES((select Id from News where sId=129),(select content from News where sId=129));
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation')
SELECT ID, C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(1000)') DataText  FROM   @xmltbl
  CROSS APPLY
 XmlData.nodes('BreezyCalc/Graph/point/@Text') n (C)

select DataText from @xmltbl

  END
```

the result should be

```
ID     DataText 
-------------------
129   |lines added
```

Comment: What is your error? what result are you actually getting? What are you actually asking?

Comment: here i have a path '/BreezyCalc/Graph/point' when i check this some time "DataText" will be null in that case i want to check else condition  like if (DataText =='') need to go for else but i don't have any idea about thanks for reply

Comment: `if ISNULL(DataText,'') =''` `BEGIN` some code here `END`, then `ELSE` `BEGIN` some code here `END`

Comment: i am getting this error Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'DataText'. Daniel E any suggestion\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Datatext as varchar(200)=''
    ,IDParameter as Int = 129
SET @Datatext= (select top 1 XMLData from @xmltbl where ID=@IDParameter)

if ISNULL(@DataText,'') ='' 
    BEGIN 
        some code here 
    END
ELSE IF (Some Other Condition)
    BEGIN 
        some code here 
    END
```

You can leave out the `IF (Some Other Condition)` if it is an either or logical flow.